# Revision History of Google Cloud Platform Terms of Service

Tags: google-app-engine

Does anybody has different versions of Google Cloud Platform Terms of Service so revision history can be tracked?

Now I see [it](https://cloud.google.com/terms/) as "Last modified: May 20, 2015", but I would like to see how it changed over time...

Comment: Hey! As has been pointed out by konqi and the users who put your question on hold, this is not really appropriate for Stack. I would suggest asking the same question, but on Google Group for app engine : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine

Comment: no worries at all. I'm just sending you to the groups as you might get a better reception than a closed question :)

Answer (score 1):

Not that this is a stackoverflow question, but have you tried the [web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/*/https://cloud.google.com/terms/)?